# Classification of subfields of $K(S)$

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

Let $F:K$ be a field extension and $S \subset F$. Is there any classification of subfields of $K(S)$ In case this isn't standard, $K(S)$ is the intersection of every subfield containing $K$ and $S$, i.e.

\begin{equation*}
   K(S) = \bigcap_{\substack{L \supset K \cup S \\ L \text{ is a subfield of } F}} L.
\end{equation*}

I couldn't find anything, but my intuition is telling me that the only subfields of $K(S)$ are either

1. subfields of $K$;
2. subfields of the form $K(T)$, where $T$ is "built" from $S$.

I'm not exactly sure what "built" should be, but my thoughts so far are that elements of $T$ should be linear combinations of elements of $K(S)$ with coefficients in $K$. However, I am at a loss of how to start proving this.

If not, can we say something along these lines if $S$ is a finite set, say $S = \{\alpha_1, \dotsc, \alpha_n\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Apologies, I made a silly error in my construction of $K(S)$. What I wrote is correct if you assume that $K(S)/K$ is algebraic. If not, then you must instead consider quotients of these sums. For instance, if we look at $K(x)/K$ then the set I wrote out is just $K[x, x^{-1}]$, which is not equal to $K(x)$. The rest of the argument holds the same way, but with a broader notion of $T$ being "built" from $S$.

Your conjecture is essentially correct, and here's a way to prove it. We have an expression for a generic element of $K(S)$ as sums of the form $\sum a_i s_i^{n_i}$ where $a_i \in K$, $s_i \in S$, and $n_i \in \mathbb Z$ (I'm assuming here that $0 \notin S$). This will indeed be a field containing $K$ and $S$, and clearly any field containing $K$ and $S$ must contain this. Now, let $K(S)/E/K$ be an intermediate extension. Then every element of $E$ is of the form of the sum I wrote above, so any generating set $T$ of $E$ over $K$ will necessarily consist of such elements as well. In that sense, $T$ is wholly "built" from $S$.

For completion, I want to emphasize that you cannot strengthen this to say that $T \subseteq S$ or even that elements of $T$ are $K$-linear combinations of elements of $S$. Take for instance $K(x)/K(x^2)$. You do really need these to be *algebraic* combinations, not just linear ones.

Also, I'd like to point out that any discussion of the set of intermediate fields in an extension $F/K$ warrants some mention of Galois theory. In certain nice cases, subgroups of the group of automorphisms of $F$ that fix $K$ (called the Galois group of $F/K$) completely determine the intermediate fields in a very elegant fashion.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm asking this question in the context of Galois theory, but haven't gotten to the Galois group yet. I don't mind assuming that $K(S)/K$ is algebraic, but I had one question- What changes if $0 \in S$? Wouldn't this only mean that some terms in the sums $\sum a_i s_i^{n_i}$ are zero?

Comment: Ah yeah so the $0 \notin S$ assumption was needed to write an element of $K(S)$ as that sum, not a quotient of those sums (in the algebraic case). Notice that the exponents are integers, not just natural numbers, so for that to make sense we can't include 0.

Comment: Ahh I see, thanks!